# How to access $http.get caller variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angular-promise

Consider this simple angularjs code:

```
$http.get( url ).then(function ( response ) {
    var cache = new Cache(url);
    cache.response = response;
});
```

My problem is the above code is nondeterministic. Sometime the url do not match when the response is get from the server.

I would like to edit 10 contact data simultanously. 
So for that to work, I would like to cache the requests to the server and put it into a javascript object.

I have written a simple service to achieve that, but suffers from the above bug.

Here is the code:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('save', function($http, $q) {

    // Private object
    var Cache = function(url) {
      this._url = url;
      this.response = {};
      this.saveDeferred = null;
      this.saveDeferredFulfilled = false;
    };

    Cache.prototype.$save = function () {
      return $http.put( this._url ).then(function (response) {
        this.response = response;
        return response;
      });
    };

    //public method
    var draft = {
      caches: {},
      get: function ( url ) {
        if (draft.caches.hasOwnProperty(url)) {
          return draft.caches.url.response;
        } else {
          return $http.get( url ).then(function ( response ) {
            var cache = new Cache(url);
            cache.response = response;
            return cache;
          });
        }
      },
      save: function(url) {
        if (draft.caches.url.saveDeferred) {
          if (!draft.caches.url.saveDeferredFulfilled) {
            draft.caches.url.saveDeferred.reject(new Error('forced timeout'));
          }
          draft.caches.url.saveDeferred = null;
          draft.caches.url.saveDeferredFulfilled = false;
        }

        draft.caches.url.saveDeferred = $q.defer();
        draft.caches.url.response.version = (parseInt(draft.caches.url.response.version) + 1).toString();

        $http.put(url, draft.caches.url.response)
          .success(function(data) {
            console.log('some data returned');
            console.log(data);
            draft.caches.url.saveDeferredFulfilled = true;
            draft.saveDeferred.resolve(data);
          })
          .error(function(error) {
            console.log('Some error occured in save.creates');
            console.log(error);
            draft.saveDeferred.reject(error);
          });
        return draft.saveDeferred.promise;
      }
    };

    return draft;
  });
```

It must be something really basic, what I'm missing here.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this article http://geek.bluemangointeractive.com/caching-http-requests-in-angularjs/.

Comment: I would advise against using URL as a cache key in your case. It might be a cleaner approach to use unique keys for your entities and cache them based on those keys rather than volatile url strings.

Comment: My problem is that i do not understand variable scope in promises, so I would very much see the original question answered. However thank you mic4ael letting me know about the builtin cache service and also thank you Constantine for the tip about cache keys.